# Sprite Kit detect contact

Tags: ios7, collision-detection, sprite-kit

I have four Sprites: Ball, Objects, Line and Stars.
I defined also categories:

`static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x1 << 0;
 static const uint32_t objectsCategory = 0x1 << 1;
 static const uint32_t lineCategory = 0x1 << 2;
 static const uint32_t starsCategory = 0x1 << 3;`

properties:

```
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = objectsCategory | starsCsategory;
object.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = objectsCategory;
object.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
star.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = starsCategory;
star.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
line.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = lineCategory;
line.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = objectsCategory;
```

now in my `didBeginContact` method (thats ok) :

```
    if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & lineCategory ) == lineCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & lineCategory ) == lineCategory ) {

    score++;
    scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)score];

}
    if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & ballCategory ) == ballCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & ballCategory ) == ballCategory ) {

    [self gameOver];


}
```

the other part ( this not works):

```
if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & starsCategory ) == starsCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & starsCategory ) == starsCategory ) {

    score = score + 100;
    scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)score];

}
```

Where is my fault? I want: when the ball "contact" the star, i get 100 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: (starsCsategory)

```
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = objectsCategory | starsCsategory;
```